# Donut tutorial: Weird mesh

Tags: mesh, solidify-modifier

I'm a beginner and am following a YouTube tutorial from Blender guru.
Now I ran into a "problem". For now it doesn't really matter or make any problems, but I'm afraid it'll do, if I don't fix it.
Sonmehow one part of my mesh has more edges and vertices that I can't delete without destroying the mesh.
[image: mesh]
[image: Solidy on]

I don't know how I can fix this, to look and function like the rest of the donut.
Did I do something wrong? Should I start again? Or is there any fix?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're learning Blender from scratch and particularly following a tutorial like Andrew's donut one, I'd always advise saving your blend file under a different name at the end of each section. That way you can start again from just before you noticed a problem rather than having to start the whole thing again. You can use Ctrl-Shift-S to 'Save as' and increment the filename by clicking the '+' at the end of the filename field in the file selector. Also doing the section again will probably show where you went wrong the first time!

Comment: I have a similar sentiment to John, however I always recommend when doing the donut tutorial that _every time_ you make a mistake, close the file and start again from the _very beginning_ - sure it seems like a pain in the butt, but the repetition will make you much more intuitively familiar with blenders systems, and you will start performing actions much, much faster. By the end, you'll be able to do the whole donut scene in 15 minutes with no help.

Comment: As far as your problem goes, grab the "middle two" horizontal edges at the top of the offending section, press G, G, (edge slide), and drag them right down to the bottom. Do the same thing loose vertices that are left over on the line (individually) a, but instead of dragging them down, drag them into an adjacent vertex (try to keep a quad "outline" when choosing the vertices to move). Once that is all done, select the whole thing in edit mode, press M (merge), and select "by distance" to get rid of the extra verts you piled on top of one another..

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem!
I started the icing new, so I'm practicing it, but I also want to learn from my mistakes and learn how I made them. I guess I extruded something and messed it up without noticing.